# Do I need to create a stored procedure to check the hostname exists?

Tags: c#, sql

I want to check if the hostname exists in the database or not. Due to I have 50 machine PC to run the exe. Now, I am using

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Machines 
WHERE hostname = @hostname
```

but I get an error which same as attached image. Do I need to create a stored procedure for checking if the hostname exists? (I am new programmer)

I am getting the following error message:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@hostname".

[image]

Code:

```
string hs = Dns.GetHostName();
string str = "";

using (var db = new SystemDbContext())
{
     Machine mc = db.Machines.Where(m1 => m1.hostName == hs).FirstOrDefault();
            
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=192.168.200.202;Initial Catalog=machine_reader;Uid=sa;Pwd=Gmtonlin3");
     con.Open();

     // sql command for checking if hostname exists
     SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Machines WHERE hostname = @hostname", con);

     int hostExist = (int)check.ExecuteScalar();                                                

     // check hostname by using count table row
     if (hostExist > 0)                                                                           
     // hostname exist, update last read date time
     {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_MR_UPDATEMACHINEINFO", con);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         DataSet dt = new DataSet();
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
         da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Machines", con);
         da.Fill(dt);
     }
     else                                                                                     
     // hostname does not exist, insert new record
     {
         string myIP = Dns.GetHostByName(hs).AddressList[0].ToString();
         Machine m = new Machine
                {
                    hostName = hs,
                    ipAddress = myIP,
                    pbDir = "C:\\NUDBDB\\PostBond",
                    prbDir = "C:\\NUDBDB\\PreBond",
                    lastReadAt = DateTime.Now
                };
         db.Machines.Add(m);

         try
         {
             db.SaveChanges();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(ex);
         }
     }

     con.Close();
 }
```

Comment: You're not passing `@hostname` to the command, but you're using it in the query.

Comment: I assume you need to add the parameter to your check command.

Comment: Can I write like this statement?                                                                       
SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Machines WHERE hostName = '" + hs + "'", con);

Comment: Erm.. Starting out so well with parameterized queries etc, and then reverting to concatenating a value in is a terrible idea... Use `check.Parameters.Add("@hostname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = hs;` instead